# Request entity too large error for PNG Image on S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3

I had an entity too large error when trying to upload image to amazon s3. The strange thing is it has error for a png file just merely have 85kb size.

I tried with other png which has more than a hundred kb I didn't get the error.

```
var data = {
          Key: file_name,
          Body: buffer,
          ContentEncoding: 'base64',
          ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
        };

        s3Bucket.putObject(data, function(err, data){
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              res.send({result:0});
            } else {
              res.send({result:1,file_name:file_name});
            }
        });
```